# redraw view off screen - contains picker view and tool bar

Tags: ios, ios7, uipickerview, uitoolbar, uivewcontroller

Im trying to draw/place a view (which contains a picker view and a toolbar offscreen). On launch the View is still on the screen despite changing its coordinates in viewDidLoad.

```
 self.pickerViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 722, 320, 207);
```

Im using the storyboard. I have created the view in the storyboard, visible in the view controller. I thought i could redraw it off screen as per coordinates above.

Comment: Have you try to add your code in -(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
It will surely work with autolayout.

Comment: This worked too! An is probably a more correct answer

Comment: Posted as an answer hope this will help some one else too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When you use Auto layout** write your view's frame related code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Here is a solution

```
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
self.pickerViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 722, 320, 207);
}
```