# Change UIButton frame inside UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, frame

I want display different `UIButton`/`UILabel`/`UISlider` sizes on an iPhone 4/4s screen. In the parent ViewController `viewDidAppear:` method I was able to set new button frames by calling my `viewFormatting` function.

```
- (void) viewFormatting
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

        //iPhone 4
        if (result.height == 480)
        {
            self.myButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
            self.myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
            //etc.
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try calling the same method `viewFormatting` inside `initWithFrame:` on separate UIView class the button/label frames do not resize. I also tried calling the function inside `layoutSubviews`. I put a `NSLog` inside `viewFormatting` so I know it is getting called correctly, but the button/label frames do not change.

Note: In both scenarios I have created the outlets in XIB files.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Write it in ViewDidLayoutSubview

Comment: Is this the case ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515924/redraw-view-off-screen-contains-picker-view-and-tool-bar/19532803#19532803

Comment: are you using **AutoLayout**?

Comment: Not using AutoLayout, do I need to call viewDidLayoutSubview? Or is it automatically called like viewDidAppear?

Comment: @nburk Ah, I was using AutoLayout. I unchecked that and it works fine. Didn't realize that individual xibs could use auto layout individually. Thanks!

Comment: @Seslyn, viewDidLayoutSubview will called automatically like viewDidAppear , and if you are developing new application use storyboard and size classes

Comment: @Jageen thanks for your help! I figured out my issue was with AutoLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Thanks to @nburk I realized that the use AutoLayout was checked on my xib file. After removing that the code above works perfectly.

I'll leave it here for anyone who needs a sample.

Comment: Then you could accept your own answer so it's easier to notice.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method:
    -(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self viewFormatting];
    }

viewDidLayoutSubviews get called automatically.